# Banach spaces admitting no proper quasi-affinity

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am interested in examples of Banach spaces $X$ satisfying the following two conditions:

(1) Every (continuous linear) injective operator $T:X\to X$ with dense range is surjective.

(2) $X$ is isomorphic to its hyperplanes.

Observations:

(a) A space satisfying these two conditions must be non-separable [[GK]](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2034182?__redirected), and 
it cannot admit an infinite dimensional separable complemented subspace.

(b) There are non-separable H.I. spaces that satisfy (1), but H.I. spaces fail (2).

(b) In [[AKo]](http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.3042) we can find an example of a non-separable $C(K)$ space in which every injective operator is surjective, but it fails (2).

Comment: This is related to the question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/101253,  but we (Nasseri, Schechtman, Tkocz, and I) now know that $\ell_\infty$ fails (1) (that solves Problem 1 in your book with Martinez-Abejon). The paper should be ready soon; I'll send you a copy when it is done if we don't immediately post it on the ArXiv.

Comment: So $X$ cannot contain copies of $\ell_\infty$.